# See if a user has subscribed to a list on landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

```
          var listName = ListArr[i].List.Name;
          var prefName = Variable.SetValue("@PrefName",listName);

          var list = List.Init(listName);
          var subbed = "";

          var checkSub = list.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"Subscriber Key",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:subKey)};
```

This giving me a 500 error.  I am trying to test a subscriber against all lists to see if they are subscribed.  `ListArr` returns a info on spoof subscriber that is subbed to all lists in the BU so I can test `checkSub` against each list name and generate a checkbox accordingly.  `checkSub` is causing the error, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with it.  Is there a different way to see if a user is subscribed to a list, preferably through SSJS?

EDIT: Upon further investigation, none of the List Subscriber functions are working at all.  I have hardcoded this:

```
  var subkey = "*My Email*";
  var MyList= List.Init(*List ID*);
  var Subs = MyList.Subscribers.Retrieve({Property:"SubscriberKey", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:subkey});
```

And I have made sure I am the only person on that list.  I still get zero results.  In addition, I cannot add new subscribers to that any lists via ssjs and I cannot unsubscribe from lists via ssjs either.

Comment: Are you loading the platform core library like Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1"); at the start of that code?

Comment: Yeah, the rest of the ssjs works, but that one statement breaks it.

Comment: Deleting the space in Subscriber Key allows the code to run, but now it is returning an empty array.  It should return the EmailTypePreference for the subscriber it matches.

Comment: @Matt Goldstein what is your requirement can you please  explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

If you initiate the subscriber first before retrieving the lists, it will only retrieve the lists the subscriber is a part of.

Full example code below:

```
%%[
    SET @subscriberKey = _subscriberkey /*Retrieve the Subscriber Key into a variable*/
]%%

<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1")
    var subKey = Variable.GetValue("@subscriberKey") //Assign to SSJS variable
    var subObj = Subscriber.Init(subkey) //Initiate Subscriber Object

    var listJSON = subObj.Lists.Retrieve() //Retrieve lists that the subscribers is a part of
    for (var i = 0; i < listJSON.length; i++){ //Loop through all the lists and print them out in HTML

        var listName = listJSON[i]["List"]["Name"]
        var listStatus = listJSON[i]["Status"]
 </script>

 <body>

     List Name:<ctrl:var name=listName /> <br />
     List Status:<ctrl:var name=listStatus /> <br />

 </body>

<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1")    
    } //End of loop

    Write("Debug - Subscriber JSON:" + Stringify(listJSON)) //Used for debugging to find the object names

 </script>
```